# Socket EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: android, sockets

I am doing socket programming. I took reference from below link:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Below is detail about my issue. I have created Android lib for this ServerThread (my project requirement), and this is used in test app.

Now test app connect to this through lib and do the process. First time it works perfectly fine, but if I closed and reopen it crashed with exception:

> "EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)"

Also tried `serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true)` this but no luck.

My code:

```
public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception1= " + e.getMessage());
    }
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {

            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.d(TAG, "server Connected.......!!!!");

            communicationThread = new CommunicationThread(
                    socket);
            commThread = new Thread(communicationThread);
            commThread.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception 2=" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `serverSocket.close()` I am getting exception 2 as server socket close. Communication thread is same as given in previous link.

Comment: same issue as here...             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068710/java-net-bindexception-bind-failed-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use

Comment: What type of socket are you using?

Comment: How do you use the socket? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Please oh please never post code in a comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg added code in main question.. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to call `setReuseAddress(true)` before the socket is bound to the port.  You are calling it after, because you are passing the port to the constructor, which will bind the socket immediately.

Try this instead:

```java
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); // <-- create an unbound socket first
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_PORT)); // <-- now bind it
```

Comment: I tried that well but I am getting below exception                         ServerSocketThread exception 2=Socket is closed

Comment: On which line of code exactly?  Please be more specific.

Comment: While executing this line  socket = serverSocket.accept(); inside while loop.

Comment: `serverSocket.accept()` should not be throwing error 2 unless `serverSocket.close()` was called.

Comment: @qwerty the Java documentation says the parameterless constructor "*Creates an **unbound** server socket*", and does not show any 1-parameter constructor that accepts `null` as input.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Sorry, i didn't read it correctly. The null parameter is only for 
 new DatagramSocket(null). It will fix the same issue there.

Comment: WOW.... ```because you are passing the port to the constructor, which will bind the socket immediately.```

Answer (score 8):

TCP (and probably some other) sockets can't reuse the same port for a period after closing.  This is to prevent confusion if there's data on the network from an existing connection.  You can override this behavior, but the default is to wait for a period of time before allowing reuse of the port.

The call to fix this is `setReuseAddress(true)` on the server socket.  But I'm not sure if it needs to be called on the first socket or the second, or both.

Edit:

Here's a blog post describing the TCP socket TIME_WAIT state and why it exists:  http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Answer (score 4):

While other answers pointed out the importance of `setReuseAddress(true)`, another problem that could arise is to construct the ServerSocket twice and call bind with the same parameters. For example if you call twice the code `run()` of the question, `serverSocket` will be assigned to a new instance of the ServerSocket class, but the old one is still living until garbage collected. Now constructing with the port value as parameter equals to bind the ServerSocket object, and you are going to end up with two ServerSocket bound to the same address, which is forbidden hence the exception. So build your serverSocket with your chosen port only once!

Comment: Or, at least `close()` the previous `ServerSocket` before creating a new one. That way, even if the previous one habit been GC'ed yet, its socket will have released the port and `setReuseAddress()` will allow the port to be rebound while it is in the TIME_WAIT state

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the instance of SocketServer outside of the run() method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)   
    try {
        // create a new instance of an unbound socket first
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```